# Access forbidden 403 on wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

Hello I have been charged to take care of a wordpress [site](http://testimonials.hurford-salvi-carr.co.uk/) and I wanted to migrate it to a local server. I have exported my files and database to a testfolder on xammp, ran a query to change my urls to localhost and updated wp-config with new database information.

I can get access to the home page however when I try to go to my admin page, i get a,

"Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server."

This is the first time I have experienced this so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please post the content of your `.htaccess` file which is in the wordpress root folder. If you have a different structure on your localhost, the problem is probably there.

Comment: Hi thank you for pointing me to .htaccess, I found that in my admin section, the .htaccess was set to deny from all, possibly for security reasons. I have changed it and now have access. thanks